# Is the Current active user profile the Owner?

Tags: android, android-account

Starting from Lollipop, Android introduced Multiple user profiles.Where user can add new user or a guest user.My application will be installed in Owner profile.When a message is received to my application it play audio on loudspeaker.

So Basically i want to detect where device is running in Owner profile at the specific point ?

Ex: XxxManager.isOwnerProfileActive();

NOTE: There is way where app can figure out if the profile is in Background/ foreground.Using the Intent.ACTION_USER_BACKGROUND / Intent.ACTION_USER_FOREGROUND which will be broadcasted by system.But i am looking for an API.

Comment: You want to get the user info at the time of tone played?

Comment: Yes, i do not want to play the tone if user has changed the profile.Skype does that during incoming call.